# K-means Stopping Criteria in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Im implementing the k-means algorithm on matlab without using the k-means built-in function, The stopping criteria is when the new centroids doesn't change by new iterations, but i cannot implement it in matlab , can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: i have a set of data points , i reached that every set of points are clustered around 3 centroids , and the iterations are repeated but i don't know how to implement the stopping criteria

Comment: Maybe copy some of your code here for the function?  That way, we can make a suggestion about how to implement a change to it.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `no change` as a stopping criteria is a bad idea. There are a few main reasons you shouldn't use a 0 change condition

1. even for a well behaved function the difference between 0 change and a very small change (say 1e-5 perhaps)could be 1000+ iterations, so you are wasting time trying to get them to be exactly the same. Especially because computers usually keep far more digits than we are interested in. IF you only need 1 digit accuracy, why wait for the computer to find an answer within 1e-31?
2. computers have floating point errors everywhere. Try doing some easily reversible matrix operations like `a = rand(3,3); b = a*a*inv(a); a-b` theoretically this should be 0 but you will see it isn't. So these errors alone could prevent your program from ever stopping
3. dithering. lets say we have a 1d k means problem with 3 numbers and we want to split them into 2 groups. One iteration the grouping can be `a,b vs c`. the next iteration could be `a vs b,`c the next could be `a,b vs c` the next.... This is of course a simplified example, but there can be instances where a few data points can dither between clusters, and you will end up with a never ending algorithm. Since those few points are reassigned, the change will never be 0

the solution is to use a delta threshold. basically you subtract the current values from the previous and if they are less than a threshold you are done. This on its own is powerful, but as with any loop, you need a backup escape plan. And that is setting a `max_iterations` variable. Look at matlabs documentation for kmeans, even they have a `MaxIter` variable (default is 100) so even if your kmeans doesn't converge, at least it wont run endlessly. Something like this might work

```
%problem specific
max_iter = 100;

%choose a small number appropriate to your problem
thresh = 1e-3;

%ensures it runs the first time
delta_mu = thresh + 1;
num_iter = 0;

%do your kmeans in the loop
while (delta_mu > thresh && num_iter < max_iter)
   %save these right away
   old_mu = curr_mu;

   %calculate new means and variances, this is the standard kmeans iteration
   %then store the values in a variable called curr_mu
   curr_mu = newly_calculate_values;

   %use the two norm to find the delta as a single number. no matter what
   %the original dimensionality of mu was. If old_mu -new_mu was
   % 0 the norm is still 0. so it behaves well as a distance measure.
   delta_mu = norm(old_mu - curr_mu,2);

   num_ter = num_iter + 1;
end
```

**edit**

if you don't know the 2 norm is essentially the euclidean distance

[image]

Comment: If I understand it right, the old_mu and curr_mu are the variances of each center with their corresponding data points. So actually they are vectors with size k, that's why we need to calculate a norm?